# How to create a maintenance view in SAP with a single key field that is hidden

Tags: abap

There is a standard view /SAPAPO/SUBLOCV that looks like this: [image]

The LOCID is hidden so you can maintain the location without the ID showing:

[image]

I want to create a custom view but my table only has LOCID as its key field. So my view looks like this:

[image]

But the table maintenance doesn't work - it's just an empty screen and you can't do anything. I think this is because the only key field in the view is hidden. Is there a way around this to have a view to maintain LOCNOs without displaying the LOCID without having to use any custom code e.g. in events?

Comment: Notice the "H" attribute = Hidden. As per SAP recommendations (SAP license/access to SAP Support), you should not maintain the standard tables directly, you should always use the standard dialogs.

Comment: @SandraRossi I am trying to create a maintenance view for ZMYTABLE that where the user maintains the location name and not the ID. The view will not be used to maintain any standard tables. I used /SAPAPO/SUBLOCV as an example of the kind of thing I'm trying to do.

Comment: `I want to create a custom view but my table only has LOCID as its key field` the maintenance view and its LOCID hidden  key field in the above example are standard. Nothing prevents you from creating your own maintenance view for your Z table. What exact problem you are facing? `But the table maintenance doesn't work - it's just an empty screen and you can't do anything` give exact steps what you've done and what you expect after what you've done